# How to hide bootstrap modal in wide screen

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I will make open bootstrap modal in mobile but I won't close it clicking by any button except if I resize resolution bigger than mobile version I want close to it

I have no any code and any idea how to possible ?

Comment: Make use of `hidden-*` or `visible-*` classes in bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

You Try code:

```
if(screen.width < YourWidth){
   $('#modal').modal('hide');
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**
Give the modal the following class(es): `hidden-md hidden-lg`.

**Option 2:** Use jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width < 968 /* or any other width */){
    $('#mymodal').modal('hide');
  }
});
```

Comment: by giving hidden-md hidden-lg will not work for backdrop you can try option two is better